# Relative node position

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to replicate the very simple figure shown below

[image]

Below is the attempt I have made

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0.1) node[minimum height=0.5cm,minimum width=5cm,draw,color=white] (A2) {};
  \draw (0,0) node[minimum height=1.5cm,minimum width=3cm,draw,align=center] (A1) {Alice \\ $Q = aP$};

  \draw (7,0.1) node[minimum height=0.5cm,minimum width=5cm,draw,color=white] (B2) {};
  \draw (7,0) node[minimum height=1.5cm,minimum width=3cm,draw,align=center] (A1) {Bob \\ $R = bP$};

  \draw[thick,->] (A2.north east) -- (B2.north west) node[above=0.25cm,midway] {P};
  \draw[thick,<-,below] (A2.south east) -- (B2.south west) node[below=0.25cm,midway] {R};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I feel that manually placing the nodes and having these white hidden boxes is quite ugly. Is there a cleaner simpler aproach which uses nodes relative to each other? I tried using the `matrix` library, but the exact details eluded me. The text in the figure should ofcourse be centered (and not be of course, like it is now)

Comment: Which pgf version do you use? It is normal under 3.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are better off with `matrix` library of `tikz`

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand{\mytab}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} #1\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
            nodes={draw,minimum height=1.25cm,minimum width=3cm,draw,align=center},
            column sep=5mm, row sep=15mm, nodes in empty cells]{
        \mytab{Alice \\ $Q = aP$} & |[draw=none]|               & \mytab{Bob \\ $R = bP$}\\
        |[draw=none]|             & \mytab{Charlie \\ $S = cP$} & |[draw=none]|   \\
       };
      \draw[->] ([shift={(1cm,0.25cm)}]m-1-1.east) -- ([shift={(-1cm,0.25cm)}]m-1-3.west) node[midway,above] {Q};
      \draw[<-]([shift={(1cm,-0.25cm)}]m-1-1.east) -- ([shift={(-1cm,-0.25cm)}]m-1-3.west) node[midway,below] {R};
   \draw[->] ([shift={(0.25cm,-0.5cm)}]m-1-1.south) -- ([shift={(-0.5cm,0.25cm)}]m-2-2.west) node[midway,above right] {Q};
      \draw[->] ([shift={(-0.25cm,-0.5cm)}]m-1-1.south) -- ([shift={(-0.5cm,-0.25cm)}]m-2-2.west) node[midway,below left] {S};
    \draw[->] ([shift={(-0.25cm,-0.5cm)}]m-1-3.south) -- ([shift={(0.5cm,0.25cm)}]m-2-2.east) node[midway,above left] {S};
      \draw[->] ([shift={(0.25cm,-0.5cm)}]m-1-3.south) -- ([shift={(0.5cm,-0.25cm)}]m-2-2.east) node[midway,below right] {R};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use relative placement options then :)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[mystyle/.style={minimum height=1.25cm,minimum width=3cm,
                                        draw,align=center}
                       ]
      \node[mystyle] (A1) {Alice \\ $Q = aP$};
      \node[mystyle,right=5cm of A1] (A2) {Bob \\ $R = bP$};

      \draw[->,shorten <=1cm,shorten >=1cm] 
            ([yshift=0.25cm]A1.east) -- ([yshift=0.25cm]A2.west) node[midway,above] {Q};
      \draw[<-,shorten <=1cm,shorten >=1cm] 
            ([yshift=-0.25cm]A1.east) -- ([yshift=-0.25cm]A2.west) node[midway,below] {R};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! Sorry for pestering you, but is there also a way to add a third box between and below the A1 and A2? I am trying to do this http://i.imgur.com/qCv3GE2.png, so far I have https://www.overleaf.com/read/dncqjxdyfbqq. But the arrows and the exact placement of "Charlie" deluded me (it was tough). Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar For the QS side try `\draw[->,shorten <=0.5cm,shorten >=0.5cm,thick] 
            ([xshift=0.25cm]A1.south) -- ([yshift=0.25cm]A3.west) node[midway,above right] {Q};

      \draw[<-,shorten <=0.5cm,shorten >=0.5cm,thick] 
            ([xshift=-0.25cm]A1.south) -- ([yshift=-0.25cm]A3.west) node[midway,below left] {S};` and play with the numbers.

Answer (score 4):

For whom it may interest, here is a way of doing this with MetaPost and the `boxes` package, included in a LuaLaTeX program for convenience.

The position of the boxes is implicitly determined by the line

```
b.w = origin - a.e = a.e + (3cm, 0);
```

which tells MetaPost that they must be positioned symmetrically around the origin on the horizontal x-axis, and that the boxes' lateral borders must be separated by a distance of 3 cm.

The parameters `hgap` and `vgap` indicates respectively the horizontal gap between arrow and box, and the vertical gap between both arrows.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
    \mplibsetformat{metafun}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    input boxes;
    hgap := .5cm; vgap = 3mm; 
    beginfig(1);
      boxit.a(btex \begin{tabular}{c} Alice \\ $Q = aP$ \end{tabular} etex);
      boxit.b(btex \begin{tabular}{c} Bob \\ $R = bP$ \end{tabular} etex);
      b.w = origin - a.e = a.e + (3cm, 0);
      path join[]; 
      join1 = (a.e -- b.w) shortened hgap yshifted .5vgap;
      join2 = reverse join1 yshifted -vgap;
      drawboxed(a, b); drawarrow join1; drawarrow join2;
      label.top(btex $Q$ etex, point .5 of join1);
      label.bot(btex $R$ etex, point .5 of join2);
    endfig;
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**Edit** And now the three boxes asked for in commentary of Percusse's answer. I've changed the names of `hgap` and `vgap` into `boxgap` and `arr_gap` respectively, but their roles are unchanged. For the third box, I think it is better to place it explicitly.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
    \mplibsetformat{metafun}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    input boxes;
    path join.ab, join.ba, join.bc, join.cb, join.ac, join.ca; 
    beginfig(1);
      boxit.a(btex \begin{tabular}{c} Alice \\ $Q = aP$ \end{tabular} etex);
      boxit.b(btex \begin{tabular}{c} Bob \\ $R = bP$ \end{tabular} etex);
      boxit.c(btex \begin{tabular}{c} Charlie \\ $S = cP$ \end{tabular} etex);

      b.w = origin - a.e = a.e + (4cm, 0); c.n = (0, -2cm);

      boxgap := 5mm; arr_gap := 3mm;
      join.ab = (a.e -- b.w) shortened boxgap yshifted .5arr_gap;
      join.ba = reverse join.ab yshifted -arr_gap;
      drawboxed(a, b, c); drawarrow join.ab; drawarrow join.ba;
      label.top(btex $Q$ etex, point .5 of join.ab);
      label.bot(btex $R$ etex, point .5 of join.ba);

      arr_gap := 4.5mm;
      join.bc = (b.s xshifted arr_gap -- c.e yshifted -arr_gap) shortened boxgap;
      join.cb = (c.e --  b.s) shortened boxgap;
      drawarrow join.bc; drawarrow join.cb;
      label.lrt(btex $R$ etex, point .5 of join.bc);
      label.ulft(btex $S$ etex, point .5 of join.cb);

      join.ac = (a.s -- c.w) shortened boxgap;
      join.ca = (c.w yshifted -arr_gap --  a.s xshifted -arr_gap) shortened boxgap;
      drawarrow join.ac; drawarrow join.ca;
      label.urt(btex $Q$ etex, point .5 of join.ac);
      label.llft(btex $S$ etex, point .5 of join.ca);
    endfig;
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is yet another way to achieve the above using the cryptocode package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cryptocode).

The cryptocode way of writing protocols is more targeted towards the following style

[image]

Which is generated by:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cryptocode}

\begin{document}

\pseudocode{
\textbf{Alice} \< \< \textbf{Bob} \\
Q =aP  \< \< \\
\< \sendmessageright{top=$Q$} \<   \\
\< \< R=bP \\
\< \sendmessageleft{top=$R$} \< }

\end{document}
```

The idea is that a two-player protocol can be visualized by 3 columns the left column showing the actions of the first player, the third column the actions of the second player, while the center column contains the messages being exchanged. Switching columns is done via '\<'. You can, however, also mix tikz within the `\pseudocode` command (using `\pcdraw`) to get the original picture:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cryptocode}

\begin{document}

\pseudocode{
\pcdraw{ 
  \node[yshift=-0.35cm,draw,minimum height=0.5cm,minimum width=2cm] {\tikz{
     \node (alice) {Alice}; 
     \node[below=0.1cm of alice] {$Q=aP$};
   }};
}\phantom{AliceB } \< \sendmessageright{length=2cm,top=$Q$} \< 
\phantom{Bob }\pcdraw{
  \node[yshift=-0.35cm,draw,minimum height=0.5cm,minimum width=2cm] {\tikz {
    \node (bob) {Bob}; 
    \node[below=0.1cm of bob] {$R=bP$};
  }};
}  \\
\< \sendmessageleft{length=2cm,bottom=$R$} \< 
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here the three player solution, although this is probably now somewhat stretching the purpose of the package a bit ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cryptocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{pcimage}
\pseudocode{
\pcdraw{ 
  \node[yshift=-0.35cm,outer sep=0.1cm,draw,minimum height=0.5cm,minimum width=2cm](alicebox) {\tikz{
     \node (alice) {Alice}; 
     \node[below=0.1cm of alice] {$Q=aP$};
   }};
}\phantom{AliceB } \< \sendmessageright{length=2cm,top=$Q$} \< 
\phantom{Bob }\pcdraw{
  \node[yshift=-0.35cm,outer sep=0.1cm,draw,minimum height=0.5cm,minimum width=2cm] (bobbox) {\tikz {
    \node (bob) {Bob}; 
    \node[below=0.1cm of bob] {$R=bP$};
  }};
}  \\
\< \sendmessageleft{length=2cm,bottom=$R$,bottomname=bobsmsg} \< \\[1cm]
\< \pcdraw{
 \node[below=of bobsmsg,outer sep=0.1cm,draw,minimum height=0.5cm,minimum width=2cm] (charliebox) {\tikz {
    \node (charlie) {Charlie}; 
    \node[below=0.1cm of charlie] {$S=cP$};
   }};
%communication with alice
   \draw[->] (charliebox.north west) -- node[right=0.25cm] {$Q$} (alicebox);
   \draw[->] (alicebox.south) -- node[left=0.25cm] {$S$} (charliebox.west);
%communication with bob
   \draw[->] (charliebox.north east) -- node[left=0.25cm] {$Q$} (bobbox);
   \draw[->] (bobbox.south) -- node[right=0.25cm] {$R$} (charliebox.east);
} \<
}
\end{pcimage}

\end{document}
```

[image]